# User control (ascx) in asp.net and its bindable properties dont show up in the data container

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, listview, user-controls, properties

When I add a user control which has bindable properties to an asp.net page I do not see its bindable properties on the designer's dialog box when I click the edit Data bindings on the Repeater-Listview

should I add any other propery descriptors?

the markup would be like this inside a repeater or similar control

```
<uc1:Menu ID="Menu1" superman="<% Eval("userid") %>" runat="server" />
```

on the bindable property I only use

```
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultBindingProperty("superman")]
    [System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true)]
    public int superman
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

[People discuss it here but they couldn't find a solution](http://forums.asp.net/t/1026896.aspx/1)

[image: This is the problematic place]

---

[image: And this is the definition of the user control]

Comment: The user control you are creating is it inherting from any class? for example like Repeater or ListView ?

Comment: can you paste the code? if that possible

Comment: @MMK no it doesn't iherit from any class. I attempt to pass values to the user control with custom html attributes

Comment: dont you need to create a public property in User Control?

Comment: http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/excerpt/progaspdotnet_14/index2.html?page=2  Check this link hopefully it will give you insight what you trying to do.

Comment: Why would you ever want to set these values using the wizards from the smart tag?  All it's going to do is paste what you type into the markup, so might as well do it there (or get fancy and do it in your codebehind).  I don't see how this is worth 50 of your rep.  BTW: I was confused by your screenshot, so I'll say it here: To get to the Data Bindings wizard you show, you must right-click on the DataList in the Design View and select "Edit Template"->"Item Templates", then you will see the Custom User Control and when you hover over it you will see the smart tag for "User Control Tasks".

Comment: @MikeTeeVee add that as an answer and hit the jackpot

Answer (score 4):

I think this might be a problem with Visual Studio, I have not found a way to show the properties of user controls, but still, you can bind the property even when it does not appear in the options box:

This is how you bind it:

In the user control code behind:

```
[Bindable(true)]
public string MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return this.lblMessage.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        this.lblMessage.Text = value + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

In the ASCX file:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" Text="something" runat="server" />
```

In the ASPX page:

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dataList" Width="50%" 
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" ID="myUC" MyProperty='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetProducts" TypeName="WebApplication1.Repository">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Simple just add the property you created in your UC in the tag:

```
<uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" ID="myUC" MyProperty='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: That's also the conclusion I came to, myself. Thanks for the effort. Your answer explains the situation.

Comment: at what moment custom property can be accessed, if it binds in aspx page? mean that in UserControl.Page_Load method property == null, so where can it be used?

Answer (score -4):

I think you just make the markup by typing it,
 the user control must be drag and drop to the page in the design view.
try this may helps.